# Preciso que uma imagem SVG fique fixa a um canto de uma Div com Tamanho variado

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

queria saber como posso fazer uma imagem (svg) ficar "presa" a um canto de uma div...
ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho a DIV (roxa) e o SVG (vermelho)
sendo que a DIV tem uma largura padrão e ela n cresce mais do que isso,
já na altura ela pode variar, e daí quando ela cresce o SVG fica mais ou menos assim onde ele estava antes:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o que eu queria era que o SVG ficasse assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O SVG preso no canto inferior esquerdo da DIV...
Desculpa se eu n expliquei direito, eu sou novo nessa "área" de Css, html etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução seria colocar um position absolute no svg e ajustar com bottom e left.

Algo tipo assim: https://codepen.io/peedroo/pen/QWvJjop

Comment: Deu certo, eu estava usando TOP no lugar do Bottom por isso que quando a DIV era maior o SVG ainda ficava "preso" na parte de cima da DIV... Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que position relative na div roxa e position absolute na div vermelha, ajeitando com top e left você ajeita a posição dela. Eis o código:

```
div.pai {
position: relative;
}
svg {
position: absolute; //isso vai deixar o svg com posição absoluta relativa ao 
próximo elemento pai com position definida que não seja static
top: distância do topo aqui;
left: distância da esquerda aqui; //Valores negativos pra sair da box vermelha
;
```